# Understanding why the current can be treated like below for magentic field calculation

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

> Consider a solenoid in which the loops are tilted and not exactly perpendicular to the axis of it(ideal one) .

- When we try to find magnetic field inside and outside of it we first treat the current as having two components one being the circular one and other being the horizontal one ( shown in figure), i would like to know why we can do so ? ( That is the current can be treated like that ?).    [image]

> My thinking : Since current in the coils is not a vector so treating it like that makes it behaves like vectors so isnt that wrong ?

- Note : for my understanding i think if the answer has the form like firstly getting a expression for magnetic field and then converting that expression into vector sum of circular and horizontal current magnetic field would be more beneficial.

Comment: the current is not vector but some forms of Biot–Savart law operate with current density $\vec{j}$ that's already a vector. In usual Biot–Savart law we can meet the $\vec{dl}$ vector of wire length, in these terms the regular current contains the sense of $\vec{j}$ amplitude and $\vec{dl}$ contains the sense of $\vec{j}$ direction

Comment: I see can you once mathematically show this for the above problem ? That is starting with the setup given and getting a expression for magnetic field and then converting it into vector sum of horizontal and circular current , that way i would get more better realization in general @AslanMonahov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual Biot-Savart law looks like

[image]

Where we can set vector $\vec{e}=\vec{dl}/|\vec{dl}|$ in the current direction. So, if cross-sectional area of wire is S we can rewrite:
$$\vec{B}(\vec{r})=\dfrac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_C\dfrac{Idl\cdot\vec{e}\times\vec{r'} }{|\vec{r'}|^3}=\dfrac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_C\dfrac{|\vec{j}|\cdot Sdl\cdot\vec{e}\times\vec{r'} }{|\vec{r'}|^3}=$$
$$=\dfrac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_C\dfrac{Sdl\cdot\vec{j}\times\vec{r'} }{|\vec{r'}|^3}=\dfrac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_C\dfrac{Sdl\cdot(\vec{j}_{parallel}+\vec{j}_{round})\times\vec{r'} }{|\vec{r'}|^3}=$$
$$=\dfrac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_C\dfrac{I_{parallel}dl\cdot\vec{e}_{parallel} \times\vec{r'} }{|\vec{r'}|^3}+\dfrac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_C\dfrac{I_{round}dl\cdot\vec{e}_{round}\times\vec{r'} }{|\vec{r'}|^3}=$$
$$=\dfrac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_C\dfrac{I_{parallel}\vec{dl}_{parallel} \times\vec{r'} }{|\vec{r'}|^3}+\dfrac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_C\dfrac{I_{round}\vec{dl}_{round}\times\vec{r'} }{|\vec{r'}|^3}=$$

Comment: Thanks this clears it very much :)